# Video Playback issues (could be hardware acceleration)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, video, ffmpeg

I have an issue with video playback in various applications such as Kodi or mpv player. Sound usually is the problem and I think it is down to hardware acceleration. Often when I playback mp4 or mkv files I get super fast audio that sounds like the binars from TNG ([Audio Example](https://youtu.be/59iKpxFvBnY?t=58s))

It started some time ago probably when I switched drivers, it persisted in 16.04 when I upgraded. I use [this method](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/08/ubuntu-nvidia-graphics-drivers-ppa-is-ready-for-action) to install `nvidia-367` but have had this same problem manually installing from the nvidia site in both 15.10 and 16.04.

I do have `ubuntu-restricted-extras` installed, this setup worked perfectly well up until about 6 months ago or less.

**Issues (playing the same mp4 file):**

Kodi

- Skips chunks of video, and merges scenes together like a broken gif
- audio is mostly broken and missing

mpv player

- Audio sounds like the Binars (video) and is super fast
- Video seems fine

VLC

- Managed to tweak it to work somehow (though the settings seems default now)
- But was playing the audio fine with black video under default settings previously
- Since VLC has more settings to play with this is what I am using to experiment currently

Any help debugging would be appreciated?

VLC playout output from console with default settings (plays wit

Comment: Actually VLC player isn't fixed at all, it flicks green randomly every few seconds, or sometimes minutes. Most videos won't play on my system like they did a year ago. Frustrating!

Comment: [ffmpeg/audio] mp3: Header missing
Error decoding audio. even with the latest version of ffmpeg 3.0.1.